# How can I tell Windows to show more entries in the taskbar right-click menu of File Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

[image: screenshot]

When you right-click the taskbar button of explorer, it shows a list of favorites. It doesn't seem to be the same list in the side bar of File Explorer.

For some reason this list is limited to a fixed amount of directories. Can it be increased?

Comment: Keep in mind that those **Pinned** choices at the top represent everything you have readily available under `Quick access` when you have a `File Explorer` window open.  In other words, if you pin additional locations within `Quick access`, they will also appear on your `File Explorer` right-click taskbar menu.

Comment: @run5k if you look at the picture, those are pinned folders, not an often-accessed list of folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change the maximum number of items that appear in jumps lists utilizing the Registry Editor:

> 1. Do a search for **regedit**, then right-click and **Run as administrator**
> 2. If necessary, acknowledge the UAC prompt
> 3. Navigate to the following location:
>      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
> 4. If the **JumpListItems_Maximum** value doesn't already exist, right-click the **Advanced** key, select **New** > **DWORD (32-bit) Value**, type **JumpListItems_Maximum** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
>
>    [image: Jump List Items Maximum - Initial Value]
> 5. In the right pane of the **Advanced** key, double-click on the **JumpListItems_Maximum** value to modify it.
> 6. Select (dot) **Decimal** and type a number (11 or higher) for the maximum items you want in your jump lists, and click on **OK**:
>
>    [image: Jump List Items Maximum - Data]
> 7. The end result should resemble the following:
>
>    [image: Jump List Items Maximum - Updated Value]
> 8. Close the Registry Editor
> 9. Reboot

Source: [How to Change Maximum Number of Items in Jump Lists in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/45535-change-maximum-number-items-jump-lists-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Glad to help!  However, I don't think that Microsoft perceives that limitation as a problem.  I'm sure that for the vast majority of people, the default number of items displayed in the jump list is sufficient.  But it *is* nice to have the capability to change it behind-the-scenes.